# How to do a recursive join to get the lowest level of data with TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following set of data:

```
ID          ParentID 
----------- ---------
8320        NULL     
8321        8320     
8322        8320     
8323        8322     
8325        NULL     
8328        8325     
8329        8328
```

What I am trying to achieve is to select all the rows that belongs to a specific ID. For instance, if I am querying ID = 8320, the following data must be returned:

```
ID          ParentID 
----------- ---------
8320        NULL     
8321        8320     
8322        8320     
8323        8322
```

So far this is what I have attempted with no real success.

```
select *
from JobQueueLog JQL
    left join JobQueueLog JQLC on
        JQL.ID = JQLC.ParentID
    and JQLC.ParentID is not null
where JQL.ID = 8320
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a CTE and make a recursive query

```
with tmp (id, parentid) as (
select id, parentid
from rec
where id = 8320
union all
select rec.id, rec.parentid
from tmp
inner join rec on tmp.id = rec.parentid
)
select id, parentid
from tmp
```

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht - You can check that by changing the view to `Oldest` from `Votes`. But anyhow he answered some seconds before me I guess. To differentiate I added sample data..kind of demo

Comment: And much appreciated for the well structured and detailed demo. Ta!

Answer (score 5):

`Recursive CTE's` are meant to do this

```
WITH data
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   ( VALUES ('8320',NULL),
                         ('8321','8320'),
                         ('8322','8320'),
                         ('8323','8322'),
                         ('8325',NULL),
                         ('8328','8325'),
                         ('8329','8328')) tc ([ID], [ParentID])),
     rec_cte
     AS (SELECT [ID],
                [ParentID]
         FROM   data
         WHERE  [ID] = '8320'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT r.[ID],
                r.[ParentID]
         FROM   rec_cte rc
                JOIN data r
                  ON r.[ParentID] = rc.ID)
SELECT [ID],
       [ParentID]
FROM   rec_cte
```

**Result :**

```
╔══════╦══════════╗
║  ID  ║ ParentID ║
╠══════╬══════════╣
║ 8320 ║ NULL     ║
║ 8321 ║ 8320     ║
║ 8322 ║ 8320     ║
║ 8323 ║ 8322     ║
╚══════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;with cte
as
(
select  * from #temp where id=8320
union all
select t.* from 
cte c 
join 
#temp t on c.id=t.parentid
)
select * from cte
```